# Why are mic picture one on top of the other

Tags: bootstrap-4

[image]
why are my images padding top/bottom not working properly? 
I need them to have a spacing from the ones above/below

here is a part of the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Image Galleyy</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
 <!-- this is my nav bar -->
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Cool Pictures</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- my jumbo container -->
<div class="container">
 <div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>The Image Galerry</h1>
  <p>Nice Pics</p>
 </div>
<!-- my pics in a grid -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
     <div class="img-thumbnail">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qK42fUu.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
     </div>
    </div>
     <div class=" col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
     <div class="img-thumbnail">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1435771112039-1e5b2bcad966?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
     </div>
    </div>
      <div class=" col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
     <div class="img-thumbnail">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1442406964439-e46ab8eff7c4?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
     <div class="img-thumbnail">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qK42fUu.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
     </div>
    </div>
     <div class=" col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
     <div class="img-thumbnail">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1435771112039-1e5b2bcad966?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
     </div>
    </div>
      <div class=" col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
     <div class="img-thumbnail">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1442406964439-e46ab8eff7c4?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
     <div class="img-thumbnail">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qK42fUu.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
     </div>
    </div>
     <div class=" col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
     <div class="img-thumbnail">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1435771112039-1e5b2bcad966?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
     </div>
    </div>
      <div class=" col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
     <div class="img-thumbnail">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1442406964439-e46ab8eff7c4?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
     </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
 </div>


  

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

I am new to this and I cant seem to figure out why is the grid working for all the other padding spaces except when they go on top of each other

Comment: Please add your CSS as well. `img-thumbnail` is not standard Bootstrap. And it's the `col-lg-4 col-sm-6` classes that are giving your horizontal separation.

Comment: I dont have css, only using the link to bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, there is no padding/margin on top/bottom of `row` or `col-xx-[99]` classes in Bootstrap; So you'd have to add the `.img-thumbnail{ margin-bottom: 1rem; }` to get what you want

**working snippet**:

```css
.img-thumbnail {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- this is my nav bar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Cool Pictures</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- my jumbo container -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>The Image Galerry</h1>
    <p>Nice Pics</p>
  </div>
  <!-- my pics in a grid -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="img-thumbnail">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qK42fUu.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="img-thumbnail">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1435771112039-1e5b2bcad966?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="img-thumbnail">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1442406964439-e46ab8eff7c4?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="img-thumbnail">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qK42fUu.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="img-thumbnail">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1435771112039-1e5b2bcad966?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="img-thumbnail">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1442406964439-e46ab8eff7c4?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="img-thumbnail">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qK42fUu.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="img-thumbnail">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1435771112039-1e5b2bcad966?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="img-thumbnail">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1442406964439-e46ab8eff7c4?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I use  col-xx-[99] with regular text it spaces them evenly from all sides ... Why it doesn't when is a picture?

Comment: i am so lost! where do i add this??

Comment: Add the .img-thumbnail class inside the <style></style> block in your code